# Create image view in grid QT like in explorer

Tags: c++, image, qt, view

I need to create image's view in grid (or table), like in explorer (Win) to display them and its info( like name etc.) I use QT and C++. Which widget should I use and how?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after a [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) (or a QListView if you want to work with a model).

If you set it the [View Mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) to Icon Mode, you get something like the standard explorer file view : Icons with text underneath.

[image]

Comment: should I use ListView or TableView, which class will suit me better

Comment: A QListView (or QListWidget) will give a view like the one shown in my answer. A QTableView will give a more table-like view with multiple columns. So it really depends what kind of view you are after.